# getting element that triggered ajax call from global jquery handlers

Tags: ajax, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to know which element in body triggered AJAX request in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051276/how-to-know-which-element-in-body-triggered-ajax-request-in-jquery)

Is it possible to get the element that triggered an ajax call from jquery global handlers, ie. $(document).ajaxSend and $(document).ajaxComplete events? So I can just handle disabling/enabling buttons from these 2 locations. I currently just disable the button that is executing the call from the button's onclick event and then renabling it when the call completes.

But I'm getting lazier and would like to find a more "elegant" method. I can see event.target.activeElement from ajaxSend in FF but in Chrome it doesn't work.

Update: I basically want to do it from just 2 locations and not having to add additional code each time I want to make a button handle an ajax call properly.

Comment: @Matt should undelete his answer - it's right!

Comment: ah, you can't see it because your rep is too low.

Comment: care to tell me the answer? please?

Answer (score 0):

Only an event handler function knows which event and element triggered it, from the first parameter supplied to it.

If that handler subsequently starts an AJAX call, the only way to know why that call happened is to pass around the event and element information yourself.

Given your use case, the code to disable a button and then re-enable it again isn't *that* arduous:

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
   var self = this;

   self.disabled = true;
   $.ajax(...)
    .done(function() {
       self.disabled = false;
   }
});
```

and it would be easy to refactor that if needed.

Comment: Hmmm, under FF the event.target.activeElement in $(document).ajaxSend() actually points to the element that triggered the call but not IE and Chrome which points to body

Answer (score 0):

Closest I got was to set the context when making the ajax call

```
$.ajax({
    context: this,
});
```

where $(this) is actually the button from the button click event where the ajax call was made and then access this context via settings from ajaxSend and ajaxComplete

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (event, request, settings) {
     if (settings.context != undefined &&
        settings.context.length && 
        settings.context[0].nodeType) {
        $(settings.context).attr("disabled", true);
     }
 });
```

the wrapper would be

```
$.fn.extend({
        post: function (url, data, callback, type) {
            if (jQuery.isFunction(data)) {
                type = type || callback;
                callback = data;
                data = undefined;
            }

            return jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: url,
                data: data,
                success: callback,
                dataType: type,
                context: this.length == 0? undefined:this
            });
        }
    });
```

and now I can call $(button).post(url, callback). Shouldn't be too hard to replace all existing calls. :)