# Get the source of the event from delegate when it's on document

Tags: jquery, jquery-blockui

I am using delegate (tried live as well, same effect) to get general ajax calls and catch them so I can show a loading screen with the following code:

```
             $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document).delegate("", "ajaxStart", function(event) {
                    console.log(event);

                    $.blockUI({
                        message: "<h1 style='color: #000'>Loading ...</h1>",
                        overlayCSS: { 
                            backgroundColor: '#000', 
                            opacity: .1
                        },
                        css: {
                            border: '2px solid #000', 
                            padding: '15px', 
                            backgroundColor: '#fff', 
                                            '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                                            '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                            color: '#000'
                        }
                    });
                });

                $(document).delegate("", "ajaxStop", function(event) {
                    $.unblockUI();
                });
            });
```

The thing is that I want to put the loading block only on the element that issued the ajax call and still make it general. I have looked at the event object that the delegate call provides and didn't find any clues on how to get the source. Usually the source is a div or a table.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: check this `http://stackoverflow.com/q/5051276/405673`

Comment: This is good for some of my cases, but in some I can't find the object with the data sent or url. Anything else that may be useful? (this solves some of my problems though)

Comment: actually I think that I will just pass a param that states the id of the container and that's it. Thanks! :)