# How to check if ajax request comes from a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Im disabling all buttons when an ajax request is processing and enable them when ajax process is done and succeded. Now my question is... how do I check that the ajax request is comming from an specific element, in this case a button?

here is my code so far:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(){
    if(ajax request comes from a button) {
        $(':button').prop('disabled', true);
    }
});

$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    errorCount = 0;
    $(':button').prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Any advice will be very appriciated :) Thanks all!

Comment: What if you do `$("button").click(function() {$('button').prop('disabled', true); })` ?

Comment: you can pass the `id of button when ajax call` and using this id `disabled` the button

Comment: just bind a dedicated click-event handler for your buttons. In this handler you can trigger your request and register a appropriate event handler for when the request completes

Comment: You have 2 options in ajax call called _beforeSend_ and _success_ that can accomplish what you ask for.

Comment: mmm... I didnt thought about that :) Im gonna try it now @executable

Comment: I need the behavior for all buttons... I dont have id's on buttons :/ @Dr.Strange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lite research and use of the provided advices here I came up with the solution, here is my code now and working:

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $(document).ajaxSend(function(){
            $this.prop('disabled', true);
        });
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    $this.prop('disabled', false);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(sender){
    if(sender.tagName == 'button') {
        $(sender).prop('disabled', true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes! something like this was what i was looking for, only that tagName is not detecting my 'button's but that should be easy to do :) I'll update my code as soon as I have it working!

Comment: take a look at this :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051276/how-to-know-which-element-in-body-triggered-ajax-request-in-jquery