# is there any way to know which button was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I have been making ajax requests many times. I need to know which button I clicked

```
    <button class="ajax-btn" onclick="function_1();">Ajax 1</button>
    <button class="ajax-btn" onclick="function_2();">Ajax 2</button>
    ...
    <button class="ajax-btn" onclick="function_10();">Ajax 10</button>
    // ajax request for each button

        var ajaxBtnVal = ""; // keep button text

        $(document).ajaxStart(function(e, xhr, options) {
            $(".ajax-btn").addClass('spinner spinner-white spinner-right disabled');
            ajaxBtnVal = $(".ajax-btn").text();
            $(".ajax-btn").text('Processing...');
            // which button was clicked ?
        });

        $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
            $(".ajax-btn").removeClass('spinner spinner-white spinner-right disabled');
            $(".ajax-btn").text(ajaxBtnVal);
        });
```

Comment: `this` is here the handler you wanna use. Something like `$(this).value("changed text")` note i use `value`, since the text of a button is a value attribute

Comment: I wanna change the text of whichever button is triggered in ajaxStart().

Comment: Don't use inline event handlers like `onclick="function_1();"` `ajaxStart` only knows that ajax has started, not which element initiated the event. You should be doing this in the "click" event handler, which knows what element initiated the event.

Answer (score 0):

This should show you which button was clicked.

```
$('.ajax-btn').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).index('.ajax-btn'));
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.It is necessary to know which button the request is made, so I want to change the text of the button accordingly.

Comment: I want to change the text of the button to "saving" when the ajax request starts.It should be "save" again when the request is over.

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onclick = function (e) {
    window.clickedButton = $(e.target);
};

$(document).ajaxStart(function (e, xhr, options) {
    window.clickedButton.addClass('spinner spinner-white spinner-right disabled');

    ajaxBtnVal = $(".ajax-btn").text();
    window.clickedButton.text('Processing...');
    // which button was clicked ?
});
```

Comment: This way I will have to update all ajax requests. my goal is to handle it in one place

Comment: actually you can expand on this. I use 1 ajax call actually to handle everything in my application, because my ajax call is within a function that requires an array. This way i can simply set up an array per press and let 1 ajax request handle it all.

Comment: Please see my update.. you can pass "this" parameter from html into jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. BeforeSend () function solves the problem. But I wonder if I can find out which button is triggered inside the ajaxStart ?

Comment: This may help you. e parameter is holding triggering element  https://stackoverflow.com/a/54359424/10011511

Comment: I have updated my answer, it may help you.

Comment: in this case e.target references to #document not button

Comment: I made another update. Please see above. This may help.

Comment: I added the conditions ( `if ((window.clickedButton).is(":button"))` , `if (window.clickedButton.hasClass('ajax-btn'))` ) from your answer.then the clicked button is reached.Is it a good way to listen to every click ? because this will work not only for the button but for all clicks through the #document.

Comment: @Savas Karaduman Thanks I solved it from the link you give.